# Google App Engine - NeedIndexError: no matching index found

Tags: python, google-app-engine, indexing, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to do simple query:

```
entity = DeviceLocation.query(ndb.StringProperty('deviceID') == data['deviceID']).order(-DeviceLocation.timestamp).get()
```

Every time it raises the next error:

```
NeedIndexError: no matching index found. recommended index is:
- kind: DeviceLocation
  properties:
  - name: deviceID
  - name: timestamp
```

The problem is even if I'm trying to create index (guided by this - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/indexes), the deploy command (`gcloud app deloy index.yaml`) returned this:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Server responded with code [400]:
  Bad Request Unexpected HTTP status 400.
  Creating a composite index failed for entity_type: "DeviceLocation"
ancestor: false
Property {
  name: "timestamp"
  direction: 2
}
: This index:
IndexDef{form=SCANNER_BUILTIN_SINGLE_PROPERTY, kind=DeviceLocation, isAncestor=false, propertyDefs=[PropertyDef{path=timestamp, direction=DESCENDING, mode=null}]}
is not necessary, since single-property indices are built in. Please remove it from your index file and upgrade to the latest version of the SDK, if you haven't already.
```

As I understand it, there is a contradiction between errors. This is relevant either to `group_by` and `projection`.

For now, couldn't run any complex queries and it prevents me from making any progress.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually this is not a 'simple query' because you are filtering by `deviceID` and ordering by `timestamp`.

GAE directs you to create a composite index, this is what you have to append to your `index.yaml` file:

```
- kind: DeviceLocation
  properties:
  - name: deviceID
  - name: timestamp
```

Make sure you included these two properties (`deviceID` and `timestamp`) in this particular order.

The last thing to improve is the way you're filtering by property:

```
DeviceLocation.deviceID == data['deviceID']
```

Comment: Can't believe that it was so easy to make it work! thank you! wish it would help other people, because it been difficult to understand in other questions that posted here.